# GNU Make, building unnecessary dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my makefile I have a rule alike this;

```
res/resource.me: res/lengthy_dependency
   ... code that builds resources.me assuming lengthy_dependency is present ...

res/lengthy_dependency:
   ... Download 10GB data and stuff ...
```

This is all nice and dandy, however when running res/resource.me while it is built and res/lengthy_dependency is removed to save space.
I get the lengthy_dependency running, instead of the "nothing to be done for res/resource.me".

If I comment out the body of res/lengthy_dependency, and keep everything else static; I do get the "nothing to be done for res/resource.me".

Why does the details of how to build res/lengthy_dependency affect if it's built or not?

Note: res/lengthy_dependency doesn't have any sub-dependencies.
Edit: It seems any body in res/lengthy_dependency triggers a rebuild of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (more or less) what the `.SECONDARY` special target is for.  If you add rule making something dependent on `.SECONDARY` it will only be rebuilt if specifically asked for or needed for a non-existant target:

```
.SECONDARY: res/lengthy_dependency
```

Now `res/lengthy_dependency` will only be downloaded if you specifically ask for it on the command line, or if something that depends on it needs to be rebuilt for some other reason.

Comment: Lovely, it's working :) - I never knew about SECONDARY until now.